# trying to rotate on x axis with CSS and keep children rotating only on 2d axis

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

So I have a ring that I am rotating a dot around and I am trying to keep the dot always facing forward, so it doesn't go flat like a flipping card... if that makes sense.  I want to follow the rotation of the parent but not skew to 2d... not really sure how to better explain it.

I have an example of what I am working with in the Fid link, I want it to do exactly that, but keep the dot flat and visible all the way through the rotation... sorry if I sound like a tool. :)

`a link`http://jsfiddle.net/cvQGn/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following you. Mind clarifying a bit. Maybe a diagram of some sort could help?

Comment: That might be sarcastic, but I'll give it a try anyway, if you look at that fiddle link I provided, you see how the little orange dot flattens out as is moves around?  I want it to follow the same movement path but not flatten out.